# Programatically: Android ListView at top and EditText & Button at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the code that I have so far. What should I change so that it looks like the ASCII art below?

```
private RelativeLayout mMainLayout;
private LinearLayout mButtonLayout;
private ListView mListView;
private EditText mMessageInput;
private Button mSendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(mMainLayout);
    mMainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    mListView = new ListView(this);
    mMainLayout.addView(mListView, 0);

    mButtonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mButtonLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
    mMessageInput = new EditText(this);
    mMessageInput.setMinimumHeight(200);
    mButtonLayout.addView(mMessageInput, 0);

    mSendButton = new Button(this);
    mSendButton.setText(R.string.send);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonLayout.addView(mSendButton, 1);
    mMainLayout.addView(mButtonLayout, 1);
}
```

```
-------------------------
|ListView               |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
-------------------------
| EditText      |Button |
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private LinearLayout mMainLayout;
private LinearLayout mButtonLayout;
private ListView mListView;
private EditText mMessageInput;
private Button mSendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mMainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
mMainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
setContentView(mMainLayout);
mMainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

mButtonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mButtonLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
mMessageInput = new EditText(this);
mMessageInput.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
mButtonLayout.addView(mMessageInput, 0);

mSendButton = new Button(this);
mSendButton.setText(R.string.send);
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
mSendButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f));
mSendButton.setMinHeight(300);
mButtonLayout.addView(mSendButton, 1);
mMainLayout.addView(mButtonLayout, 1);

mListView = new ListView(this);
mListView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
mMainLayout.addView(mListView, 0);
```

You should make your layout from bottom to top like above code.
so first add bottom two button in layout then add list view.
I hope its helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
private LinearLayout mMainLayout;
private LinearLayout mButtonLayout;
private ListView mListView;
private EditText mMessageInput;
private Button mSendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mMainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(mMainLayout);
    mMainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    mListView = new ListView(this);
    mListView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
    mMainLayout.addView(mListView, 0);

    mButtonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mButtonLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f));
    mMessageInput = new EditText(this);
    mMessageInput.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    mButtonLayout.addView(mMessageInput, 0);

    mSendButton = new Button(this);
    mSendButton.setText(R.string.send);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSendButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f));
    mSendButton.setMinHeight(300);
    mButtonLayout.addView(mSendButton, 1);
    mMainLayout.addView(mButtonLayout, 1);
```